# How to initialize Elasticsearch REST client

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

Assume I have a cluster containing master-eligible nodes, data nodes and coordinating nodes. When I initialize a REST client, which of the above node types should I include? All of the nodes, only the data nodes, only the coordinating nodes, or some combination thereof?

For example:

```
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
new HttpHost("master-eligible-node-1", 9200, "http"),
new HttpHost("master-eligible-node-2", 9200, "http"),
new HttpHost("master-eligible-node-3", 9200, "http")).build();
```

or,

```
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
new HttpHost("master-eligible-node-1", 9200, "http"),
new HttpHost("master-eligible-node-2", 9200, "http"),
...
new HttpHost("master-eligible-node-n", 9200, "http"),
new HttpHost("data-node-1", 9200, "http"),
new HttpHost("data-node-2", 9200, "http"),
...
new HttpHost("data-node-n", 9200, "http"),
new HttpHost("coord-node-1", 9200, "http"),
new HttpHost("coord-node-2", 9200, "http"),
...
new HttpHost("coord-node-n", 9200, "http")).build();
```

As a second part, is it possible to initialize the REST client only to coordinating nodes, or only to data nodes? I was thinking that I might want to do that if I want to isolate query operations vs indexing operations.

Thanks!

Comment: You can have different rest clients for different operations. If you know that some nodes are only for reading then you add those to your `reading rest client` and if some are for writing then to another rest client. If some nodes are for both then you add those nodes to both of your rest clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule of thumb is:

1. **never** connect directly to the master-eligible nodes
2. if you have dedicated coordinating nodes, use them
3. otherwise connect to your data nodes, which also act as coordinating nodes by nature

Comment: According to this [Elastic discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/when-to-use-coordinating-vs-data-node/134125), I should connect clients that perform queries to coordinating nodes.  Clients that update the index should be connected to data nodes.  From the advice from @alkis, I see that I can create separate clients.

Comment: But according to this [Elastic discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/rest-client-initialization/134128), I should not necessarily route read requests to coordinating nodes and write requests to data nodes.  Since creating a client is the most fundamental operation, it would be nice to have some clear direction.

Comment: Luca is right, coordinating nodes are not necessary/beneficial in all setup (as you induce an additional hop in all your requests). You need to test that first on your cluster, the ultimate answer depends on your setup and there is no definite answer.